# Using RSS as loss function for linear regression does not work

Tags: optimization, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I wanted to use [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) as loss function for a linear regression problem. I know that MSE is used normally for linear regression, but I wanted to test RSS and check my understanding of computing the gradients for stochastic gradient decent.
The gradient of RSS is 
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \theta}=-2\mathbf{X}^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\theta)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
And I use stochastic gradient decent (SGD) to update $\theta$:
$$\theta_{i+1} = \theta_{i} - \epsilon*\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \theta}$$ where $\epsilon$ is my learning rate.
I have implemented this using a sample database of scikit-learn: `fetch_california_housing`. But for some reason this gradient does not improve RSS but increases RSS until it reaches infinity. 
The code is written in Python using Numpy. The main part is the `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# read the database
housing = fetch_california_housing()

# seperate X and y
data = housing['data']
targets = housing.target.reshape(-1,1)

# standardize data 
standardized_housing_data = (data - np.mean(data))/np.std(data)

# devide in train and val set
trainset = standardized_housing_data[:int(0.75*len(standardized_housing_data)),:]
valset = standardized_housing_data[int(0.75*len(standardized_housing_data)):,:]
y_train =  targets[:int(0.75*len(standardized_housing_data)),:]
y_val = targets[int(0.75*len(standardized_housing_data)):,:]



# run SGD with RSS loss function
lr = 0.0001
epochs = 500

m,n = trainset.shape
m_val, n_val = valset.shape

X = np.c_[np.ones((m,1)),trainset]
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,1)
theta = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(n+1,1))

for i in range(epochs):
    # here is the main part
    y_pred = X@theta                     # compute y
    error = y_train - y_pred             # compute error
    RSS = np.sum(np.square(error))       # compute RSS
    gradients = (-2)* XT@(error)         # compute Gradient of RSS
    theta = theta - lr*gradients         # update theta
    print('Epoch: ', i, ' RSS: ', RSS)
```

As you can see, I am outputing the RSS of each iteration. The output is:

```
Epoch:  0  RSS:  62335.37853901445
Epoch:  1  RSS:  1601265.8854023307
Epoch:  2  RSS:  1052093835.5520192
Epoch:  3  RSS:  720335492107.2932
Epoch:  4  RSS:  493223770672591.75
Epoch:  5  RSS:  3.377172389891606e+17
Epoch:  6  RSS:  2.312397339932849e+20
Epoch:  7  RSS:  1.5833309172297123e+23
Epoch:  8  RSS:  1.0841289038709424e+26
Epoch:  9  RSS:  7.423182781429204e+28
Epoch:  10  RSS:  5.082757447915687e+31
...
Epoch:  106  RSS:  8.22215327892994e+303
Epoch:  107  RSS:  5.629823762515433e+306
Epoch:  108  RSS:  inf
Epoch:  109  RSS:  inf
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Do I compute the gradient wrongly? Is this a numerical problem?